# jQuery quiz (multiple choice, input)

Tags: jquery

In order to build my website, I'm trying to make different forms of quizzes. As for now, I'm using this one: https://codepen.io/helloayo/pen/ZBvEag

My question / request would be: is it possible to make the same quiz but with input text instead of multiple choice options?

Also, a feature that should be present for both input and multiple choice types, explanation for each wrong question?

For some reason, the snipped code throws an error, but ignores it as the code works just fine both on jfiddle, codepen and my website as well.

```js
(function ($) {
  $.fn.emc = function (options) {
    var defaults = {
        key: [],
        scoring: "normal",
        progress: true
      },
      settings = $.extend(defaults, options),
      $quizItems = $("[data-quiz-item]"),
      $choices = $("[data-choices]"),
      itemCount = $quizItems.length,
      chosen = [],
      $option = null,
      $label = null;

    emcInit();

    if (settings.progress) {
      var $bar = $("#emc-progress"),
        $inner = $('<div id="emc-progress_inner"></div>'),
        $perc = $('<span id="emc-progress_ind">0/' + itemCount + "</span>");
      $bar.append($inner).prepend($perc);
    }

    function emcInit() {
      $quizItems.each(function (index, value) {
        var $this = $(this),
          $choiceEl = $this.find(".choices"),
          choices = $choiceEl.data("choices");
        for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
          $option = $(
            '<input name="' +
              index +
              '" id="' +
              index +
              "_" +
              i +
              '" type="radio">'
          );
          $label = $(
            '<label for="' + index + "_" + i + '">' + choices[i] + "</label>"
          );
          $choiceEl.append($option).append($label);

          $option.on("change", function () {
            return getChosen();
          });
        }
      });
    }

    function getChosen() {
      chosen = [];
      $choices.each(function () {
        var $inputs = $(this).find('input[type="radio"]');
        $inputs.each(function (index, value) {
          if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            chosen.push(index + 1);
          }
        });
      });
      getProgress();
    }

    function getProgress() {
      var prog = (chosen.length / itemCount) * 100 + "%",
        $submit = $("#emc-submit");
      if (settings.progress) {
        $perc.text(chosen.length + "/" + itemCount);
        $inner.css({ height: prog });
      }
      if (chosen.length === itemCount) {
        $submit.addClass("ready-show");
        $submit.click(function () {
          return scoreNormal();
        });
      }
    }

    function scoreNormal() {
      var wrong = [],
        score = null,
        $scoreEl = $("#emc-score");
      for (var i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
        if (chosen[i] != settings.key[i]) {
          wrong.push(i);
        }
      }
      $quizItems.each(function (index) {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($.inArray(index, wrong) !== -1) {
          $this.removeClass("item-correct").addClass("item-incorrect");
        } else {
          $this.removeClass("item-incorrect").addClass("item-correct");
        }
      });

      score = ((itemCount - wrong.length) / itemCount).toFixed(2) * 100 + "%";
      $scoreEl.text("You scored a " + score).addClass("new-score");
      $("html,body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 50);
    }
  };
})(jQuery);

$(document).emc({
  key: ["2", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1"]
});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
@import url("//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,800");
@import url("//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
.row:after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.row:before {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #fff;
  font-family: "Raleway";
  line-height: 1.55;
  color: #737373;
  font-weight: 400;
}
body a {
  color: #27b198;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}
body a:hover {
  border-color: #eeeeee;
}

code {
  background: #fff;
  color: #999999;
  padding: 2px 8px;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #1f8f7b;
  border-bottom: 1px solid dareken(#2dceb1, 15%);
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  padding: 12px 0;
  background: #fafafa;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}

.wrap {
  max-width: 48em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2.5em 0 4em;
}

.row.last {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 12em;
  float: left;
  background: #fafafa;
  border-top: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  border-left: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}
section:nth-child(even) {
  border-right: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}
section.item-incorrect {
  background: #f6f6f6;
}
section.item-incorrect:before {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 399;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border: 35px solid;
  border-color: transparent #ff5c61 #ff5c61 transparent;
}
section.item-incorrect:after {
  line-height: 1.4;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 499;
  font-family: "fontawesome";
  content: "";
  bottom: 0;
  right: 7px;
  font-size: 1.9em;
  color: #ff383e;
}
section.item-correct:before {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 399;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border: 35px solid;
  border-color: transparent #48d7bd #48d7bd transparent;
}
section.item-correct:after {
  line-height: 1.4;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 499;
  font-family: "fontawesome";
  content: "";
  bottom: 0;
  right: 7px;
  font-size: 1.9em;
  color: #2dceb1;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
input[type="radio"] + label {
  background: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  margin: 5px 10px 5px 0;
  border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s linear;
  transition: all 0.1s linear;
}
input[type="radio"] + label:before {
  content: "\f10c";
  font-family: "fontawesome";
  margin-right: 7px;
  color: #2dceb1;
}
input[type="radio"] + label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background: #50d9c0;
  color: #1f8f7b;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
  content: "\f192";
  color: #1f8f7b;
}

.question {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.submit {
  padding: 20px 5px;
}
.submit button {
  display: block;
  outline: none;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 1em auto 1.5em;
  padding: 0.8em 1em;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  color: gainsboro;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}

#emc-score {
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.55s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.55s ease;
  transition: all 0.55s ease;
}
#emc-score.new-score {
  opacity: 1;
  background: #2dceb1;
  color: #fbfbfb;
  padding: 20px;
}

#emc-submit {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.33s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.33s ease;
  transition: all 0.33s ease;
}
#emc-submit.ready-show {
  background: #2dceb1;
  color: #1f8f7b;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #26af96;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.2);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(360deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(360deg);
  -o-transform: rotateX(360deg);
  transform: rotateX(360deg);
}
#emc-submit.ready-show:hover {
  color: #fbfbfb;
  background: #27b198;
  border-color: #1f8f7b;
}
#emc-submit.ready-show:active {
  top: 2px;
  border-bottom: none;
}

#emc-progress {
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #1f8f7b;
  background: #2dceb1;
}

#emc-progress_inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  background: #1f8f7b;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.33s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -moz-transition: height 0.33s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  transition: height 0.33s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}

#emc-progress_ind {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 7px 5px 5px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #1f8f7b;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(251, 251, 251, 0.85);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 25px 12px 10px;
}

.attrib {
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.attrib i {
  margin-right: 7px;
  margin-left: 7px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- questions taken from http://davidshariff.com/quiz/ -->
<header>
  <small>Multiple Choice Quiz w/ jQuery</small>
</header>
<div id="emc-score"></div>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="row">
    <section data-quiz-item>
      <div class="question">Are CSS property names case-sensitive?<br>Ex: <code>baCkgRouNd: #333;</code></div>
      <div class="choices" data-choices='["Yes","No"]'>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section data-quiz-item>
      <div class="question">Does setting <code>margin-top:</code> and <code>margin-bottom:</code> have an affect on an inline element?</div>
      <div class="choices" data-choices='["Yes","No"]'>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <section data-quiz-item>
      <div class="question">The <code>translate()</code> function can move the position of an element on the z-axis.</div>
      <div class="choices" data-choices='["True","False"]'>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section data-quiz-item>
      <div class="question">The pseudo class <code>:checked</code> will select inputs with type radio or checkbox, but not option elements.</div>
      <div class="choices" data-choices='["True","False"]'>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <section data-quiz-item>
      <div class="question">Does setting <code>padding-top:</code> and <code>padding-bottom:</code> on an inline element add to its dimensions?</div>
      <div class="choices" data-choices='["Yes","No"]'>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section data-quiz-item>
      <div class="question">If you have a <code>p</code> element with <code>font-size: 10rem;</code>, will the text be responsive when the user resizes / drags the browser window?</div>
      <div class="choices" data-choices='["Yes","No"]'>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div class="row last">
    <section data-quiz-item>
      <div class="question">In a HTML document, the pseudo class <code>:root</code> always refers to the html element.</div>
      <div class="choices" data-choices='["True","False"]'>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section data-quiz-item>
      <div class="question">The formula context/target = result is useful when building responsive layouts.</div>
      <div class="choices" data-choices='["True","False"]'>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div class="submit">
    <button id="emc-submit">Submit Answers</button>
  </div>
</div>

<footer>
  <div id="emc-progress"></div>
</footer>
<div class="attrib">
  <p>Take the full quiz <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i> <a href="http://davidshariff.com/quiz/" target="_blank">http://davidshariff.com/quiz/</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can make use of almost any form element that you like. Please clarify what it is you would like to do, what have you tried, and what is not working for you. Consider taking the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: It's possible but you will need to parse the inputs that user enter using radio you have only two options. User may type anything into input.

Comment: Not exactly sure how i should've edit the line code to transform it into an input..